# How to check if multiple values contain a CSV dataset with Python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to check if the CSV file contains all the states from the U.S. As you can see in my code I've imported the CSV file as a list in Python. I'm trying to solve this problem, without using pandas or another module.

I've created a list of the states, but I'm wondering what is the most efficient solution to check what how many states the CSV dataset contains?

```
import csv

with open('president_county_candidate.csv', newline='', encoding='utf_8') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = list(reader)

print(data)

[['state', 'county', 'candidate', 'party', 'votes'], ['Delaware', 'Kent County', 'Joe Biden', 'DEM', '44518'], ['Delaware', 'Kent County', 'Donald Trump', 'REP', '40976'], ['Delaware', 'Kent County', 'Jo Jorgensen', 'LIB', '1044'], ['Delaware', 'Kent County', 'Howie Hawkins', 'GRN', '420'], ['Delaware', 'Kent County', ' Write-ins', 'WRI', '0'], ['Delaware', 'New Castle County', 'Joe Biden', 'DEM', '194245'], ['Delaware', 'New Castle County', 'Donald Trump', 'REP', '87687'], ['Delaware', 'New Castle County', 'Jo Jorgensen', 'LIB', '2932'], ['Delaware', 'New Castle County', 'Howie Hawkins', 'GRN', '1277'], ['Delaware', 'New Castle County', ' Write-ins', 'WRI', '0'], ['Delaware', 'Sussex County', 'Donald Trump', 'REP', '71196'], ['Delaware', 'Sussex County', 'Joe Biden', 'DEM', '56657'], ['Delaware', 'Sussex County', 'Jo Jorgensen', 'LIB', '1003'], ['Delaware', 'Sussex County', 'Howie Hawkins', 'GRN', '437'], ['District of Columbia', 'District of Columbia', 'Joe Biden', 'DEM', '31723'], ['District of Columbia', 'District of Columbia', 'Donald Trump', 'REP', '1239'], ['District of Columbia', 'District of Columbia', ' Write-ins', 'WRI', '206'], ['District of Columbia', 'District of Columbia', 'Howie Hawkins', 'GRN', '192'], ['District of Columbia', 'District of Columbia', 'Jo Jorgensen', 'LIB', '147'], ['District of Columbia', 'District of Columbia', 'Gloria La Riva', 'PSL', '77'], ['District of Columbia', 'District of Columbia', 'Brock Pierce', 'IND', '28'], ['District of Columbia', 'Ward 2', 'Joe Biden', 'DEM', '25228'], ['District of Columbia', 'Ward 2', 'Donald Trump', 'REP', '2466'], ['District of Columbia', 'Ward 2', ' Write-ins', 'WRI', '298'], ['District of Columbia', 'Ward 2', 'Jo Jorgensen', 'LIB', '229'], ['District of Columbia', 'Ward 2', 'Howie Hawkins', 'GRN', '96'], ['District of Columbia', 'Ward 2', 'Gloria La Riva', 'PSL', '37'], ['District of Columbia', 'Ward 2', 'Brock Pierce', 'IND', '32']]

states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 
'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Idaho', 'Hawaii', 
'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 
'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi',
'Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico',
'New York', 'North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon',
'Pennsylvania','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas',
'Utah','Vermont','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia', 'Wisconsin','Wyoming']
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple `for` loop? What exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is only to

> check if the CSV file contains all the states from the U.S

then you can find the unique set of states in your file and make sure they count exactly as 50.

```py
number = len(set(record[0].lower() for record in data[1:]))
# Expected: number should be 50
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will count every state found in your `data` list:

```
counter = {}
for state, *_ in data:
    if state in states:
        counter.setdefault(state, 0)
        counter[state] += 1

for state in states:
    print("{:<20} {}".format(state, counter.get(state, 0)))

print()
print("Total states found:", len(counter))
```

Prints:

```
Alabama              0
Alaska               0
Arizona              0
Arkansas             0
California           0
Colorado             0
Connecticut          0
Delaware             14
Florida              0
Georgia              0
Idaho                0
Hawaii               0
Illinois             0
Indiana              0
Iowa                 0
Kansas               0
Kentucky             0
Louisiana            0
Maine                0
Maryland             0
Massachusetts        0
Michigan             0
Minnesota            0
Mississippi          0
Missouri             0
Montana              0
Nebraska             0
Nevada               0
New Hampshire        0
New Jersey           0
New Mexico           0
New York             0
North Carolina       0
North Dakota         0
Ohio                 0
Oklahoma             0
Oregon               0
Pennsylvania         0
Rhode Island         0
South Carolina       0
South Dakota         0
Tennessee            0
Texas                0
Utah                 0
Vermont              0
Virginia             0
Washington           0
West Virginia        0
Wisconsin            0
Wyoming              0

Total states found: 1
```

---

P.S.: To speed up, you can convert `states` from `list` to `set` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('president_county_candidate.csv', newline='', encoding='utf_8') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = list(reader)

states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 
'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Idaho', 'Hawaii', 
'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 
'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi',
'Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico',
'New York', 'North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon',
'Pennsylvania','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas',
'Utah','Vermont','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia', 'Wisconsin','Wyoming']

for state in data:
    for i in states:
        if state == i:
            print(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a tip: It is probably easier to use `csv.DictReader` in this case as it will give you labelled rows and automatically skip the first now. Not necessary, but makes the code easier to read

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv') as f:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(f))

print(data)

# prints: [
#    {'state': 'Delaware', ' county': ' Kent County', ' candidate': ' Joe Biden', ' party': ' DEM', ' votes': ' 44518'},
#    {'state': 'Delaware', ' county': ' Kent County', ' candidate': ' Donald Trump', ' party': ' REP', ' votes': ' 40976'}
#    ...
# ]
```

Then, you can use this expression to get all the states that are mentioned in the csv file:

```py
states_in_csv = set(line['state'] for line in data)

print(states_in_csv)
# {'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', ... }
```

`line['state'] for line in data` is a list comprehension that extracts just the 'state' field of each of those lines. `set()` makes the set of those states, i.e. removed all duplicates.

Then, you can easily test how many of your states are represented in your table. For example:

```py
num_states = 0
for state in [""]:
    if state in states_in_csv:
        num_states += 1
print("number of states:", num_states)
```

This is very efficient because checking if a value is in a set is a constant time operation, so you don't have to search your whole table for each state.

It looks like your `states` list contains every state. If you just want to know how many states were in the table, you can simply use `len(states_in_csv)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap or in this case a **Python Dictionary** that is the most efficient data structure for this job. This snippet can help you:

```
dict={}
for i in data:
    #verify if the state exist
    if i[0] in states:
        if  i[0]  in dict.keys():
            dict[i[0]] +=1
        else:
            dict[i[0]]=1

for k in dict.keys():
    if dict[k]>1:
        print(f"There are {dict[k]} times the {k} state")
```